# Height of AVL tree with random elements

Tags: sorting, tree, binary-trees, bounded-depth

I know that for an AVL tree of N nodes, the depth of the tree is bounded by
$$ \log_2(N + 1) -1 \leq height \leq c \log_2(N + 2) + b$$

where $c,b$ are taken from the golden ratio linked to the worst case of the tree, i.e. $c = 1/ \log_2(\varphi)$ and $b = c/2 \log_2(5) - 3$.

I am interested in reducing this bound (up to some probability) granted that the elements inserted in the trees are generated randomly, with entropy $H$. In my application, I have exactly $2^k$ elements of size $2^l$ to be inserted, where $k\ll l$.

I know that asymptotically a randomly generated tree will have depth very close to the theoretical lower bound, and I could find some experimental results reducing this upper bound - I can refer to ***Data Structures and Algorithms*** by Drozdek or ***The Art of Computer Programming*** by Knuth (which itself refers to the work of C. C. Foster) - but I am looking for a more concrete answer with error probability rather than only asymptotic arguments or experimental results. Would you happen to have any material support discussing this approach, of random or pseudo-random insertions in a sorted tree?

**Note:** For those interested, Knuth suggests an average of  $1.01 \log(N) + 0.1$ comparisons for the $N$th insertion in an AVL tree with random elements, except for small $N$. From my own experiments, it seems that a close upper bound would be $1.2 \log(N) + 0.1$, though I could not test it over $2^{24}$ due to insufficient memory.

Comment: Are you aware of Flajolet's work on average-case analysis of data structures?  I don't know if there is anything specifically relevant to your question, but if you haven't checked you might try.  E.g. https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/114872.114881

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thanks! I'll check this out

Comment: In their book "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms", Sedgewick and Flajolet give the generating function of AVL trees of some height. May be you can derive a formula for your problem from this generating function, but it doesn't seem to be easy.